# Getting host information in capistrano task

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

given

```
task :test do
    on roles(:app), in: :parallel do |host|
        puts host
    end
  end
```

How can I use `host` (or some other way) to get the hosts's capistrano details such as what stage the host is in, what roles, tags, etc?

since host is in the context of an SSH session, there is no way to debug this

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "since host is in the context of an SSH session, there is no way to debug this". What have you tried?

Comment: I can't "play around" inside the block via pry or similar

Comment: I added `require "pry"; binding.pry` within an `on` block and it works fine for me. If you have multiple servers involved, try `in: :sequence` so that multiple threads are not involved, which might mess up pry.

Comment: ah ok, I'll try :sequence, maybe thats what I am looking for. Thanks!